# Music won't sync with iPod

Tags: music

So, I just threw all of my music from my iPod 4G (Photo) into the pantheon music app, and all's good there. But when I try to sync my iPod through the music app, I just an error message.

Here's a picture of what I'm talking about.

[image]

The only other thing I have running is Chromium, so I have no clue as to what operation it's talking about.

Is there something I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this a [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/noise/+bug/1181152) with Music.

Until this problem is fixed, you could use a standalone sync app such as gtkpod or sync using music player such as Rhythmbox.